# How to configure AWS SSO for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-cognito

I followed this tutorial [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-enable-secure-access-to-kibana-using-aws-single-sign-on/). But I am getting the dreaded error:

```
Invalid samlResponse or relayState from identity provider
```

[image]

I am able to sign in with the `Cognito User Pool` as an identity provider, with an account I created and everything works fine, but I can't get around this error when trying to sign in with a user I created in AWS SSO which has been added to the Kibana App I created.

Comment: I've stumbled across your question, I'm in a similar position. Did you ever figure this one out?